# Custom STS and expired password via WS-Trust scenario

Tags: security, wcf-security, wcf-client, wif

Are there any guidelines or best practices for handling expired passwords for scenario with active clients via WS-Trust?

For now I have couple of ideas, but can't find any info about it:
1. Issue special token, so client can determine, that is should show change password notification.
2. Throw specific exception.

Maybe I am missing something in WS-Trust standard?

Im using WIF built-in implementation, so it is 1.3 version of standard with parts of 1.4.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WS-Trust 1.3 and 1.4 uses [SOAP Fault mechanism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/soap_fault.htm). There are a handfull of faultcodes specified in the standard.

[WS-Trust Error Handling](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/v1.4/errata01/os/ws-trust-1.4-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc325658986)

You can use wst:FailedAuthentication SOAP Fault code and provide second-level detail fields to explain password expired situation, but you should be careful not to introduce security vulnerabilities when doing so (e.g., by providing too detailed information).

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I have missed it and there is some shortage of info regarding this topic.